# What's the best place to ask this question: "Should I Worry About Modifying a Database that Serves Content on the Fly in ASP.NET"?

Tags: discussion, site-rec

What's the best place to ask this question?:

> I have a database that serves up the content for what will be a public
>   website. In this site, certain users that work for our organization
>   will be able to use a partial CMS I have built to change the contents
>   of many of the pages.
>
> My concern is this:
>
> During the "Save" process, AJAX makes a round-trip to the server, and
>   while there, nullifies the page locations of the appropriate page (so
>   as to reuse the id), then immediately afterwards re-saves the new
>   values to the page. Reading content from a NULL location will not
>   cause errors or anything; it simply won't show up on the page.
>
> I really don't mean to pick this apart too much but I am concerned
>   that I might accidentally be setting myself up for error. My question
>   is: Should I worry about the fraction of a second between nullifying
>   the locations of content and when the new content gets saved?
>
> Again, it is fault tolerant as much as possible, and I wouldn't expect
>   to see any YSODs or anything, but what if they get no content, simply
>   because somebody looked up the page, and it happened to be timed just
>   right to "get in" and get the values from the database just when
>   someone was saving edits to the given page?
>
> Anyway, I feel a little silly as I write this question, as if I am
>   over-complicating the issue or perhaps worrying too much, but
>   considering the cost if I'm wrong in my approach here, I was looking
>   for some professional advice from anyone who has programmed CMS or
>   CMS-like websites in the past.
>
> **Things You May Want to Know:**
>
> 1. I am in a C#.Net Web-Pages w/ WebMatrix environment (as opposed to Web-Forms or MVC).
> 2. The command I am using to "nullify" the page location values looks like this: `UPDATE ContentObjects SET location = NULL WHERE location =
>      @0`. Then, as soon as I programmatically can, I re-apply the values
>      and repopulate the locations.

I was thinking super user, but then I thought about how much database information was in it, as well as an understanding of asp.net perhaps, so I'm really not sure what the *best* site to ask this on is.

Comment: Transactions...

Comment: @allquixotic I'm sorry, but I don't see that one on any of the SE sites. Am I really missing it? I clicked all and even used the browser's Ctrl + F function

Comment: I meant "Transactions" as in **Database Transactions**. Use them. You're right to be cautious about updating a database and creating a potential race condition where a client may be getting wrong data. Transactions are designed to address this. Issue multiple SQL statements in the context of a transaction, and only commit once the state is consistent. This is an okayish question for SuperUser, but you really don't need to ask it -- if you are worried enough to ask "should I be worried about", then the answer is always **yes**. It's how to deal with it that you need to care about.

Comment: @allquixotic Okay, I see, well I am only just now hearing about this. I'm not sure what it even is at this point. Do you know of any good sites to introduce me to this?

Comment: When in doubt, [read Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_transaction). You didn't state which database product you're using, so it's impossible to provide more specific details. It's possible, but very unlikely, that your database implementation doesn't support transactions.

Comment: @allquixotic Actually, I did, albeit indirectly. Using Web-Pages means I am using SQL server CE

Comment: @allquixotic Well, maybe there are other options? Not sure, but anyway, thank you very much for your help. :)

Comment: Transactions are [supported](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172400.aspx) in SQL Server CE (albeit with some limitations). For your use case I don't think the limitations will be a problem. I googled: "SQL Server CE transactions". This was the first hit.

Comment: @allquixotic Thank you for pointing me in the right direction. It seems I have my work cut out for me here...

Answer (score 2):

I think this is more qualified for [Stack Overflow,](https://stackoverflow.com/) since it is to deal with how to program such a thing. They will have support for any language you are choosing to program with.